# Persist user on App Reinstall with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When a user deletes and reinstalls my app, I want their anonymous user account to persist. My iOS app is working as expected, but Android is not. I create anonymous users like so

```
if (auth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
    auth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {});
}
```

When I delete the app and reinstall, `auth.getCurrentUser()` is null and I have to re-authenticate.

My AndroidManifest.xml contains `android:allowBackup="true"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is null becase `Firebase Anonymous Authentication` accounts **does not persist across application uninstalls**. If you uninstall the application, everything that was saved locally will be deleted, including the anonymous auth token that identifies that account. There is no way to reclaim that token for the user. You can use `Firebase Anonymous Authentication` to create and use `temporary accounts` to authenticate users in your application.

These temporary anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed up to your app. If such an anonymous user decides later to sign up to your application, you can link their sign-in credentials to the anonymous account. What should you do, you should encourage your users to fully log in with a supported account provider so that they can log in from all their devices without worry of losing their data.

Comment: But is there any other possibility in working around the problem? I would like to enable my users to not enter any personal data and still recover the app status on a different device.
I consider creating and using a userId and related password on the device and use these for exporting and validating user. But as i understand i have to create a CustomToken and add custom claims. This leads to additional self hosted infrastructure and additional problems.

Comment: It is possible on iOS devices. If your app's "bundle ID" is the same, it will keep your old "Anonymous Authentication ID". There is another interesting case: On an iOS device, uninstall the app from your device, re-download the app, turn off your network connection, open your app, you can see your old "Anonymous Authentication ID", but how? (tested on a TestFlight build)