# Two users on Same Device | setUserID behaviour

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to confirm one use case, for that, I didn't find any documentation. If two user logs in the same device and I am using setUserId method, then what will happen? here is my understanding:
whenever a new app installed in a phone(ios/Android) then Firebase registers an anonymous user for that device lets say "Device-A". when setUserID(user1) method is used(when user1 logs-in in the app) then Firebase starts identifying this user with that user id lets say "user1". Now, user1 logs out from app and another user lets say user2 logs in the app and again setUserID(user2) happens. So in this case How Firebase handles? 
   1. will firebase assign this userID "user2" to the same anonymous user "Device-A" or it will create a new user and then assign this user id?

Comment: I also asked this question from Google help : I got following reply: The user_pseudo_id will be the same for the two users since it's the same app instance. In your example, it would be "Device-A". However, the user_id will be different for the two users. In your example, it would be "user1" for the first user, and "user2" for the second user. Note that the user_id persists to all events logged after setting this unless a new value is set.

Comment: How it's reported on the Firebase console would depend on your setting for the reporting identity. If you have the "By User-ID and device" setting, the analytics data logged for your users would be separate as it's dependent on the user_id set on the app. Otherwise, if you have "By device only" setting, since it's dependent on the user_pseudo_id, the data collected for your two users would be merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If two user logs in the same device and I am using setUserId method, then what will happen?

For each authenticated user you'll get a separate uid.

> Now user1 logs out from app and another user lets say user2 logs in the app and again setUserID(user2) happens?

When you are using anonymous authentication, user identification details like the `uid` is stored **only** on the device. When you sign out, their identification details are wiped out from the device. So signing out is not an option in this case because at every new authentication, a completely new `uid` is generated. Please note that you have no option to recover those identification details once there are removed. For more information you can also check my answer from the following post:

- [Persist user on App Reinstall with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098543/persist-user-on-app-reinstall-with-firebase)