# Persisting anonymous credentials after uninstall firebase - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can not figure out if this should work or not.

- According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098543/persist-user-on-app-reinstall-with-firebase) it should NOT work. But it's also from 2017.
- According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users#persist_a_users_credential) it should be stored in the Keystore services, which seems to only be erased if you log out.
- Played a couple of other games that I'm confident uses firebase as well, and they seem to be able to log me back in after I uninstall the app (without connecting to Facebook or similar)
- Also as a side note iOS keeps the credentials also after uninstall and are able to log back in

Comment: If you uninstall the app or if you sign out an anonymous user, it's the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks, so this is not consistent behaviour across platforms then. Do you happen to know if its possible to get an anonymous user back somehow? If the token/userId is stored elsewhere could it then be reauthenticate.

Comment: No, you cannot. There is no way you can get back the anonymous auth token, once you uninstall the app or when the anonymous user signs out.

Comment: Stumble this issue on android today - seems after uninstalling and reinstalling the app Firebase Authenticator can still reproduce the token